# Please Help, Unable to get TP Link T4UH AC1200 to work in Ubunutu 16.10

Tags: networking, drivers

So I have a TP Link AC1200 T4UH wifi dongle and I am unable to get it to power on or work at all in Ubuntu 16.10. 
So far I have tried to use the DKMS rtl8812au drivers that linux downloaded on startup, I have tried purging drivers, and then downloading and reinstalling them.

I have been at this for a few days now and I am completely stuck. The device works in Windows 10 without issue. I am trying to make the switch to Linux but the driver issues are doing my head in. Any help would be much appreciated.

I am very new to Linux, but do have basic understandings.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

As it happens,I used a TP Link dongle on my HP laptop.It installed fine with the default Linux (16.04)drivers.I did have to go into BIOS and deactivate the built in wifi card.After that it worked.Hope this helps til someone more knowlegable sees you question.You should edit your question to include your hardware configuration.